# What set does $x\in ^{o}$ refer to?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

If: $f(x)=|x-3|$ and $g(x)=2$

Solve the inequality $|x-1|<2$

I got a solution of:

$1<x<5,x\in R$

But the solution in the back the book said:

$1<x<5,x\in ^{o}$

Is this a typo or what set is $x\in^{o}$ ?

Comment: I have never seen that notation before, and my guess is on typo.

Comment: The solution to $|x-1| < 2$ is $-1 < x < 3$, not $1 < x < 5$.

Comment: Math fonts can lead to various typesetting issues. This must be one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typo.  It's probably also fine to not say $x \in \mathbb{R}$, since they haven't even specified the domain for $x$ in the problem.